# Understanding MapStateToProp and Resolving my Error

Tags: react-redux, react-native

I'm new to react native and after following some videos on the net to make my project work, I hit a wall because of redux and my understandings of it.
I'm stuck with an error in MapStateToProp and i can't seem to correct it.
Here are the screenshots of it: [Error at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzpFc.png)
[Message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uv2P.png)

If you could help me understand how to resolve my error it would be great

Comment: Try logging your (global) `state` in `mapStateToProps` to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: I suggest setting up react-native-debugger. It allows you to see your state and has a lot of other tools to help with redux and development in general. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your state, at that time, doesn't have `room` key inside of it.

Are you providing proper initial state inside your reducer function?

It may look as easy as below (I'm assuming your reducer function is in a separate file):

```
const initialState = {
  room: {},
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    /handle actions/
  }
 }

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You posted very little code, so its hard to say for sure. But it looks like your global state does have the expected structure of state.room.rooms. Print out the state at this point of time.

Hint: During development it can help to expose the store to be accessed from outside. If you put this line where you create the store you can access it for example via console `store.getState()`. It will return the current state of your app.

To enable this just put this line where you create your store:

```
window.store = store;
```